# Use Adventureworks database with other databases?

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there any way I can port the AdventureWorks2012 database to other databases?

For example, if I need to use it in Oracle, Teradata, MySQL, PostgreSQL or any other database. The idea is to use a single data model to develop an understanding on different databases. This will help keep the focus on the nuances/features of the database rather than the data model.

Comment: It is good practice but AdventureWorks in Oracle and Teradata and maybe PostgreSQL don't have that similar schema. For high performance, AdventureWorks schema is basic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Chinook Database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database).

> Chinook is a sample database available for SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc. It can be created by running a single SQL script. Chinook database is an alternative to the Northwind database, being ideal for demos and testing ORM tools targeting single and multiple database servers.
>
> Dec 2, 2012: Chinook Database 1.4 has been released! In this release we added support for two more databases: DB2 and PostgreSQL. Thanks to BriceLambson for implementing the PostgreSQL support! This is the list of the new changes: